# Renaming of files for a given pattern

Tags: python, file, rename, file-rename

I need help.
there is a folder "C:\TEMP" in this folder are formatted files "IN_ + 7123456789.amr"
It is necessary to make renaming of files for a given pattern.
"IN_ NAME _ DATE-CREATE _ Phone number.amr"
Correspondingly, if a file called "OUT_ + 7123456789.amr" the result format "OUT_ NAME_DATE-CREATE_Phone number.amr"

The question is how to specify the file name has been checked before os.rename and depending on the file name to use the template

```
import os

path = "C:/TEMP"


for i, filename in enumerate(os.listdir(path)):
    os.chdir(path)
    os.rename(filename, 'name'+str(i) +'.txt')
    i = i+1
```

Comment: "*how to specify the file name has been checked*"  checked for what?  Perhaps if you showed some code I might understand?

Comment: Checking for the presence of words in the file name, such as word of in / out / Phone

Comment: Дима, Update the question with the piece of code you specified in comment

Comment: Did you check the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) module?

Comment: @bufh this module does not make a simple search in a folder?

Comment: @ДмитрийИнкогнито yes, like that you would iter only on files matching the pattern required to be renamed (i though that would work for you). Or maybe i misunderstood your question (for clarity, could you state a file name which should be renamed, one which should not and the expected result in both case please?)

Comment: @bufh There are files, IN_ + 7921565656_10 / 08.amr, OUT_ + 79556323_10 / 59.amr.
You must rename them in the following form:
IN_21 / 07/10 15_ / 08_ + 7921565656.amr
OUT_21 / 07 / 15_10 / 59_ + 79556323.amr where:
21/07/15 - the date the file was created
10/08 and 10/59 file creation time

Comment: Do you mean just rename, or are you trying to also build a full directory structure as you are using `/` characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but none of your examples are consistent in your question, I still don't understand what your `C:\temp` contains...

Well, assuming it would look like:

```
>>> os.listdir(path)
['IN_ + 7123456789.amr', 'OUT_ + 7123456789.amr']
```

The example:

```
import datetime
import re
import os

os.chdir(path)
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    match = re.match(r'(IN|OUT)_ \+ (\d+).amr', filename)
    if match:
        file_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.stat(filename).st_mtime)
        destination = '%s_%s_%s_Phone number.amr' % (
            match.group(1), # either IN or OUT
            match.group(2),
            file_date.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S'), # adjust the format at your convenience
        )

        os.rename(filename, destination)
```

Will produce:

- IN_7123456789_20150721094227_Phone number.amr
- OUT_7123456789_20150721094227_Phone number.amr

Other files won't match the `re.match` pattern and be ignored.